# Using Python with Websockets?

Tags: python

I'm monitoring unconfirmed transactions from Blockchain.info API.  Here's my Python code:

```
import json
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv")
ws.send("""{"op":"unconfirmed_sub"}""")
while True:
    tx = ws.recv()
    data_decoded=json.loads(tx)
    hash=data_decoded['x']['hash']
    addr=data_decoded['x']['out'][0]['addr']
    print(hash)
    print(addr)
```

This is connecting correctly and displaying each transaction like this:

```
{
    "op": "utx",
    "x": {
        "lock_time": 0,
        "ver": 1,
        "size": 192,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "sequence": 4294967295,
                "prev_out": {
                    "spent": true,
                    "tx_index": 99005468,
                    "type": 0,
                    "addr": "1BwGf3z7n2fHk6NoVJNkV32qwyAYsMhkWf",
                    "value": 65574000,
                    "n": 0,
                    "script": "76a91477f4c9ee75e449a74c21a4decfb50519cbc245b388ac"
                },
                "script": "483045022100e4ff962c292705f051c2c2fc519fa775a4d8955bce1a3e29884b2785277999ed02200b537ebd22a9f25fbbbcc9113c69c1389400703ef2017d80959ef0f1d685756c012102618e08e0c8fd4c5fe539184a30fe35a2f5fccf7ad62054cad29360d871f8187d"
            }
        ],
        "time": 1440086763,
        "tx_index": 99006637,
        "vin_sz": 1,
        "hash": "0857b9de1884eec314ecf67c040a2657b8e083e1f95e31d0b5ba3d328841fc7f",
        "vout_sz": 1,
        "relayed_by": "127.0.0.1",
        "out": [
            {
                "spent": false,
                "tx_index": 99006637,
                "type": 0,
                "addr": "1A828tTnkVFJfSvLCqF42ohZ51ksS3jJgX",
                "value": 65564000,
                "n": 0,
                "script": "76a914640cfdf7b79d94d1c980133e3587bd6053f091f388ac"
            }, {
                "spent": false,
                "tx_index": 99006637,
                "type": 0,
                "addr": "1oWiR4wBfdUjG1htJQBGvFE49t3PFcWLE",
                "value": 65564000,
                "n": 0,
                "script": "76a914640cfdf7b79d94d1c980133e3587bd6053f091f388ac"
            }, {
                "spent": false,
                "tx_index": 99006637,
                "type": 0,
                "addr": "1GSKPwn7SnVWtX7esghyurX6y9vG5EbW5i",
                "value": 65564000,
                "n": 0,
                "script": "76a914640cfdf7b79d94d1c980133e3587bd6053f091f388ac"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But right now it's just displaying the data from `['x']['hash']` and the FIRST `['x']['out']['addr']` instead of printing all of the `addr` when there's more than one like in my example.

How do I get it to print all `['x']['out']['addr']`?

Comment: Use `json.loads` to get your response as a dictionary and then use pretty much exactly the syntax you've said you want to print it?

Comment: How do I get it to print all `['x']['out']['addr']` instead of just the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hash=your_json['x']['hash']
addr=your_json['x']['out]['addr']
```

Edit: So I tested this after a comment below and json.loads isn't necessary.  This works:

```
print(x['x']['hash'])
>>>0857b9de1884eec314ecf67c040a2657b8e083e1f95e31d0b5ba3d328841fc7f
```

Also, to hit all addresses in the nested list, you are going to need to loop through them:

```
for i in range(0, len(x['x']['out'])):
    print(x['x']['out'][i]['addr'])
```

Comment: Getting this error:  ```hash=tx['hash'] 
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str```

Comment: Hmm, are you getting the data already in the format you printed above?  You actually probably don't need json.loads if it's already in this format.  I'll update the answer to fit.  Try doing it again without the json.loads step.

Comment: Got it working halfway, updated question with current code and the issue I'm having.  How do I get it to print all `['x']['out']['addr']`?

Comment: In this case, you can just use the index the three `out` entries in the nested list.  `print(x['x']['out'][1]['addr'])`
`print(x['x']['out'][2]['addr'])`
`print(x['x']['out'][3]['addr'])`
To generalize that, you would probably want to use a for loop.  `for i in range...print(x['x']['out'][i]['addr'])`   That sort of thing.

Comment: I updated it in the answer already, but in case you didn't see it, this code should work: `for i in range(0, len(x['x']['out'])):
    print(x['x']['out'][i]['addr'])`